# Is it possible to use ember components declaratively as tags?

Tags: ember.js, web-component

I have a lot of experience with AngularJS and I'm also playing around with Web Components and Polymer for a long time now.

What I really love about the these libraries and technologies, is the fact that they let me build my own components.

AngularJS gives me something called "Directives" and Web Components consists of a set of specs where one is called "Custom Elements", which pretty much does how it's called.

So with these I can do something like:

```
<my-element></my-element>
```

This is where the web goes, this is what everybody loves about HTML. Declarative tags that are easy to read and encapsulate functionality and behaviour. Also very nice: once Web Components are fully supported in the browsers, I could for example very easily remove my directive and rely on a web component, that looks and works the same without changing any code.

I know, that EmberJS has something called "Ember Components" which lets you basically build your own kind of components too. However, using them in HTML looks something like this:

```
{{#my-component}}
{{/my-component}}
```

Is it possible in EmberJS to also use components declaratively as tags?

Answer (score 1):

I actually hate that about html.  I hate the structure etc, but that's just my opinion :)

No, there isn't, your component should be declared in a template using the handlebars syntax, and compiled to js. (you can dynamically create views/components, but that's far from declarative tags).

Comment: Correct.  Use the handlebar syntax to use your ember components.  If you want to use the syntax {{#myComponent}}howdie{{/myComponent}} you're using block form.  To just use a component outright and/or pass properties to it.  Go with  {{myComponent myName="kevin"}}  technically in the non-block form, you don't "need" an endtag.

Comment: Wow, if that is what you hate about HTML you probably have a lot of fun developing web applications. Thanks for the answer anyway. :)

Comment: lol, I write operating systems and optimize software ;)  I've been bitterly writing some web apps recently (Mostly kicking and screaming about css).

Answer (score 1):

You'll be able to do that when Glimmer 2 ships with Ember. It was supposed to be in with Ember 2.x, but for some reason its still pending. With that you can use angle brackets to define components.
`<my-element></my-element>`